# Using address function in a range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to sum over a range the end of which is defined by some calculation. The problem boils down to using the address function to define the range. For example to sum C2 to C43:

```
=sum(C2:address(3,43))
```

But this is not recognised as a range. Why not and what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dynamic range and use:

```
=sum(indirect(dynamicRange))
```

see [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CAZR2EQZTHGVJKURJnQV21THLNG9eNKG9RqWNs-t4GY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks, @Daniele. I can also put the top of the range (C10 in your example) in (say) cell F2, and use C2:indirect(F2). But I also want to sum column D and I seem to have to do the whole thing again. I thought I could just put "10" in a cell and use it twice. I couldn't make that work. (Maybe I'm just trying to be too economical with intermediate calculations.)

Comment: @Pansmanser  go to see the modified sheet...now sums two columns with only one "until" cell

Comment: Easy when you know how! Thanks, Daniele!